# Puppeteer > Selecting and performing click on second div of same class

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Managed to get further with the import script and managed to log in into the backend and move around and fill some inputs but got stuck on clicking on the "External Link" div element.
Upon clicking this div a prompt appears containing the information I need. I plan to get this information using page.on('dialog', dialog => { ... }) event.

[image: ..]

Where I am stuck in clicking on the External link div. The 2 buttons share the same
Bottom class.

The markup looks like this

```
<div class="row filterBlock">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 noRemoveMultiple ">
      <div class=" form-group1 antdSelectDevise" style="width: 100%;">
         <div style="font-size: 13px; padding: 1px 3px; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-weight: bold;">Format</div>
         <div class="ant-select    form-control form-controlC  ant-select-single ant-select-show-arrow ant-select-show-search" name="Format">
            <div class="ant-select-selector"><span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input id="Format" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="Format_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="Format_list" aria-activedescendant="Format_list_0" value="" style="opacity: 0;" readonly=""></span><span class="ant-select-selection-item">JSON</span></div>
            <span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;">
               <span role="img" aria-label="down" class="anticon anticon-down">
                  <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" class="" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 ">
      <div class=" form-group1 antdSelectDevise" style="width: 100%;">
         <div style="font-size: 13px; padding: 1px 3px; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-weight: bold;">language</div>
         <div class="ant-select    form-control form-controlC  ant-select-multiple ant-select-show-search" name="lang" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="ant-select-selector">
               <span class="ant-select-selection-item">
                  <span class="ant-select-selection-item-content">România</span>
                  <span class="ant-select-selection-item-remove" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;">
                     <span role="img" aria-label="close" class="anticon anticon-close">
                        <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" class="" data-icon="close" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                           <path d="M563.8 512l262.5-312.9c4.4-5.2.7-13.1-6.1-13.1h-79.8c-4.7 0-9.2 2.1-12.3 5.7L511.6 449.8 295.1 191.7c-3-3.6-7.5-5.7-12.3-5.7H203c-6.8 0-10.5 7.9-6.1 13.1L459.4 512 196.9 824.9A7.95 7.95 0 00203 838h79.8c4.7 0 9.2-2.1 12.3-5.7l216.5-258.1 216.5 258.1c3 3.6 7.5 5.7 12.3 5.7h79.8c6.8 0 10.5-7.9 6.1-13.1L563.8 512z"></path>
                        </svg>
                     </span>
                  </span>
               </span>
               <span class="ant-select-selection-search" style="width: 4px;"><input id="FormatLang" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="FormatLang_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="FormatLang_list" aria-activedescendant="FormatLang_list_0" value="" style="opacity: 0;" readonly=""><span class="ant-select-selection-search-mirror" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4  CC  ">
      <div class="Bottom " style="margin-top: 23px;">Download</div>
      <div class="Bottom " style="margin-top: 23px;">External link</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried different selectors to get to the second div and click on it but the script either hangs or doesn't select the right element.

Alternatively I tried moving the mouse to the area using await page.mouse.move(1500, 230) and performing a page.mouse.down followed by a page.mouse.up with surprisingly no result also.

Would really appreciate any ideas at this point. Thanks

UPDATE: Found a better way to get the information for now :) The authtoken is set in localstorage after logging in so there's no need to go through all these loopholes anymore.

Comment: Do you need to click the "External link" button only after the dialog appeared? Maybe you are loosing page focus that's why the element is not found in the context.

Comment: That dialog only appears after clicking on "Get external link". It's a prompt similar to this one https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt , however don't think the script gets this far.  The main focus point is to get the text out of that prompt (shown in the first screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`page.$$`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.1&show=api-pageselector-1) (it is the shorthand for document.querySelectorAll) to select all elements with the same selector. Then you can click the 2nd `<div>` by the index `[1]` af the array. It is an [`elementHandle.click`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.1&show=api-elementhandleclickoptions) action, we perform the click on the exact div.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.class-name')

const selectors = await page.$$('.class-name')
await selectors[1].click()
```

Alternatively you could click on the element by its XPath selector selecting it with [`page.$x`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.1&show=api-pagexexpression).

*Note:* `$x` also returns an arry, so we need to grab its first element by `[0]`.

```js
const selector = await page.$x('//div[contains(text(), "External link")]')
await selector[0].click()
```

Comment: Hello. I tried it. The xpath looks really powerful to be able to do things like this. I tried it in the browser console and it workedthere.  I think it should have worked but no way to tell. Took a screenshot after it but the prompt is not visible on screen ? https://prnt.sc/t6e1c8    The   await page.on('dialog', dialog => { ... doesn't return anything also which makes me think the prompt is not actually displayed